# Load metaboxes in Wordpress using a custom plugin class and oop

Tags: php, wordpress, class, oop, plugins

I'm writing a plugin that creates metaboxes on the admin page.
I wrote a class thinking that it should work but I don't see where it fails.

The idea is that if a new object is loaded there is a possibility to set a custom name.

```
<?php 

class Loader{

public function __construct() {

    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'loadMetaBox');
    //add_action('save_post', array($this, 'save'));
    //add_action('the_content', array($this, 'custom_message'));
}

protected $_cmbName;

public function setLoader($cmbName){
    $this->_cmbName = $cmbName;
}

public function loadMetaBox(){
    add_meta_box( 'cmb_meta', __( $this->_cmbName, 'cmb-textdomain' ), 'cmb_meta_callback', 'page' );
}
};
?>
```

And called the class like this:

```
$cmb = new Loader();
$cmb->setLoader("Custom name");
$cmb->loadMetaBox();
```

This triggers a `Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_meta_box() in .../class.load-cmb.php on line 19`.

Line 19: `add_meta_box( 'cmb_meta', __( $this->_cmbName, 'cmb-textdomain' ), 'cmb_meta_callback', 'page' );`

Comment: check your error logs

Comment: `Internal Server Error` mainly occurs when missing some brackets in code. And Better to check your error logs for this put this code in wp-config file.  `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );`

Comment: Goddamnit... Thought that was on. It usually is. Anyway see updated post please

Comment: **a)** you are instantiating your object in the wrong hook, that's why add_meta_box is not available. **b)** your code wouldn't work anyway. you are calling add_meta_box on construction time, and by then your protected property isn't set yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some errors in your code:

1. Each hooked function or callback function need to be embeded in an array with `$this` as first element and the callback function slug as 2nd.
2. Is better to defined your class in $GLOBALS at the end.
3. The function names that you are using need to be a bit more custom.
4. The `cmb_meta_callback()` function is not defined.

Try this instead:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

if ( ! class_exists( 'MBLoader' ) ) {

    class MBLoader{

        public function __construct() {

            add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'load_meta_box') ); // <== HERE
        }

        protected $_cmbName;

        public function set_mbloader($cmbName){
            $this->_cmbName = $cmbName;
        }

        public function load_meta_box(){
            add_meta_box( 'cmb_meta', __( $this->_cmbName, 'cmb-textdomain' ), array( $this, 'cmb_meta_callback'), 'page' ); // <== HERE
        }

        // The metabox content
        public function cmb_meta_callback($post){
            echo '<p>'. __('TEST CONTENT') . '</p>'; // just for testing
            echo '<p>Post ID: '. $post->ID . '</p>'; // just for testing
        }
    };
    $GLOBALS['mbloader'] = new MBLoader(); // the global variable to call
}
```

Then to call your class and make it work, you will use simply:

```
global $mbloader;

$mbloader->set_mbloader("Custom name");
```

I have used that in the **`init`** hook for testing:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_a_custom_metabox');
function create_a_custom_metabox(){
    global $mbloader;

    $mbloader->set_mbloader("Custom name");
}
```

You will get something like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

Your code:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'loadMetaBox');
```

Replace With this:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', array(&$this,'loadMetaBox' ));
```

Comment: No didn't work. Same error but can you share why you create an array?

Comment: in oop concept syntax is like that so...Please refer this link: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77709/is-it-possible-to-use-object-in-add-action hope is useful for it....

Comment: Remove & and try. reference: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48085/add-action-reference-a-class

Comment: Tried to delete the & but no luck. It just won't load the `add_meta_box` function. I think I might need to global something. Google here I come...